# Sum number by previous row number using select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose there are two column name SrNo and Salary i need a third column whose result would show like as below:-

```
SrNo - Salary - Result
1    - 1000   - 1000
2    - 150    - 1150
3    - 200    - 1350
4    - 300    - 1650
5    - 250    - 1850
```

So it will increment by adding previous column value to current value and should be simply using select statements not using any loop over it.

Comment: What determines the "order" of your rows? Without a way to determine that, what you are after is impossible.

Comment: @Larnu wait i'll edit it

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a cumulative sum.

The simplest method is:

```
select t.*, sum(salary) over (order by srno) as running_salary
from t;
```

A window frame is not needed when using `order by`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the new dataset, you can achieve this using a Windowed Function and `ROWS BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT SrNo,
       Salary,
       SUM(Salary) OVER (ORDER BY SrNo
                         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Result
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: You're welcome, @namco . Please do mark this as the solution if it did help, so that future readers know it was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: How do you mark it for future readers .. can you help me out ?

Comment: [How to update and accept answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers) @namco